# free(): invalid pointer error in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Heyo, so when I was running/compiling my program within a linux server I had this error message come up. I honestly have no idea what the bug is. I have about an hour to fix my code, so it would be awesome to get an idea of what I need to correct. Thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Car.h"
    using namespace std;

    void problemOne(int arraySize) {
    int numbers[arraySize];
    cout << "Enter next number" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    int *p = numbers;

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    cout << *p;
    p++;

}
```

}

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    cout << "Enter next number" << endl;
    cin >> *numbers;
    numbers++;

}

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    cout << *numbers;
    numbers++;

}
delete[] numbers;
```

}

```
Car *p = new Car[arraySize];

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    string color;
    string model;
    int mile;
    cout << "enter the model of the car" << " ";
    cin >> model;
    cout << "enter color of the car" << " ";
    cin >> color;
    cout << "enter the mileage of the car" << " ";
    cin >> mile;

    *p = Car(model, color, mile);


}

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    cout << p->getModel() << " " << p->getColor() << " " << p->getMileage() << endl;
    p++;
    }
   }

  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  problemOne(atoi(argv[1]));
  problemTwo(atoi(argv[2]));
  problemThree(atoi(argv[3]));
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not get `numbers` from a `new[]`, you cannot pass it to `delete[]`.

And by the way, `int numbers[arraySize];` where `arraySize` is not known at compile time is not valid Standard C++, it's a compiler extension. So be careful about what it does and does not guarantee.